# Samsung Nexus S android 4.0: can't create file in dir on sdcard

Tags: android, permissions

I have a Samsung Nexus S device with android 4.0 loaded on it. I am trying to create a file in an existing folder on sdcard and get a "permission denied". In the following code, exists() returns true but canWrite() returns false. Why?

```
File exst = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  String exstPath = exst.getPath();


              File d = new File(exstPath+"/TestDir/");
              if (!d.exists())
              {
                    int b = 1;
              }
              if (!d.canWrite())
              {
                    int a = 1;
              }
```

By the way, I've added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the manifest but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone plugged into your computer?  If so, the computer will take control of the SD card and not allow it to be written to.  Try changing the connection mode to 'Charge Only' if this is the case.

Comment: I think it's a bit different on 4.0 than it was on 2.3. When I connect, it does not offer me the 4 options "PC mode", "USB storage", "Charge only" etc. It only asks me if I want to switch USB storage on or off. I copied some files onto sdcard and for that I had to have USB storage on. Then I turned it off in order to be able to launch and debug my app from my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Append getAbsolutePath() to your first line, then it should work:

```
File exst = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Update:

Reviewing my own code and other SO answers, I believe you do not use canWrite to check if a path is writable on a SD card. Instead you use Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard mounted and writable");
}
else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard mounted readonly");
}
else {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard state: " + state);
}
```

Comment: Updated answer. Also make sure the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is placed in the correct section of the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Although all the answers give partial suggestions, the problem is very likely Samsungs non-standard implementation of the API

```
    String myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath ;
    // or .getName() or .getPath() <-- these don't return everything you need.
    // same is true for the file version you're trying.

    // you have to append
```

"/external_sd/"

to the path before the file name.

Here's Samsungs explanation for their "breaking" of the API

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=162934&messageNumber=1381&startId=zzzzz~&searchType=TITLE&searchText=sdcard

it's also mentioned in several SO posts, but I don't have the links handy...

- H

[Edit Mid May, 2013] Here's the pathology of this problem:  you can get the path() by the various normal methods mentioned. Then, just write a simple file and watch it show up in the DDMS file explorer. Try hardcoding that exact path and file name OR use the /external_sd/ thing - in both cases, you will not be able to read your own file back in !  (Or you might, but it will contain garbage.)  We've verified this on three different S3 phones.  Will test more on Samsungs "real" phones via their RemoteTestingLab site and report back.